# AutoCompleteExtender - Get Primary Key into HiddenField

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use autoComplete extender in a way similar to a dropDownList.
Currently I have a dropdown List that holds a collection of companies. Selecting a company name enables me to get the value associated with the listItem.

I want to replace the dropDownList with autocomplete extender and place a text box. While typing user will be able to view the company. After selecting the company, I want to capture the value (such as company ID). I don't want this ID to be visible to user.

Please advice how to achieve this functionality with autoComplete extender.

Comment: I remember I did this a long time ago. Hacking a TextBox was not the way to do I'm afraid. Here is another track : try to search google for a ASP.NET DropDown with a autocomplete feature instead.

Comment: i dont want dropdownlist i want textbox autocomplete